# Вернуть сумму всех чисел, кратных 3 или 5, меньше переданного числа javascript

Tags: javascript

Ребята, помогите решить задачу, пожалуйста.
Только начала практиковаться на Codewars, не понимаю фразу в условии задачи(

Вот условие полностью:
Если мы перечислим все натуральные числа до 10, кратные 3 или 5, мы получим 3, 5, 6 и 9. Сумма этих кратных равна 23. Завершите решение так, чтобы оно возвращало сумму всех чисел, кратных 3 или 5, ***меньше переданного числа.*** Кроме того, если число отрицательное, верните 0 (для языков, в которых они есть). Примечание. Если число кратно и 3, и 5, считайте его только один раз.

Не понимаю фразу "меньше переданного числа" - это какое число имеется в виду?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
let sum = 0;

function solution(numbers) {
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  
 if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
   console.log(i);
 }
      else if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    } 
      else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
  else if (i < 0) {
   
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: дайте лучше ссылку на задачу

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/514b92a657cdc65150000006/train/javascript не знаю, откроется ли, но вот она) ниже @EzioMercer привел верное решение))

Comment: `const f = n => x => n * ((x-1)/n | 0) * (((x-1)/n | 0) + 1) / 2; const sum = x => f(3)(x) + f(5)(x) - f(15)(x); console.log(sum(10)); console.log(sum(100));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это значит нужно найти все числа, кратные 3 и 5, до переданного вам числа. В примере "переданное число" - это 10. Вам могут дать 100 и тогда вам надо просуммировать все числа, кратные 3 и 5 от 0 до 100 причём (например) 15 надо считать 1 раз, т.к. оно делится и на 3 и на 5.

Как один из способов можете попробовать такое решение:

```js
const calcDevidedBy3And5 = (maxNumber) => {
    
    if (maxNumber < 0) return 0;
    
    let sum = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < maxNumber; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    
    return sum;
}

console.log(calcDevidedBy3And5(0));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!! Про 10 теперь поняла, но не могу решить с суммой вопрос(( Я поняла, что нужно создать переменную для суммы, равную 0, а как дальше посчитать сумму, после условий, не понимаю(( то есть все эти цифры выводятся в консоль с помощью console.log, но как их сложить? И при выполнении последнего условия нужно вернуть 0, как это правильно написать? Буду очень признательна за ответ! Код добавила в описание :)

Comment: @Marie Вставил свой код, можете изучать :)

Comment: @Marie Если мой ответ был вам полезен, то буду очень признателен, если вы проголосуете вверх за мой ответ и пометите его верным :)

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо! Все получилось! И главное теперь все поняла :) Отметила верным ваш ответ, вверх тоже проголосовала, но пока мой рейтинг менее 15 - так что голос учитывается, но не отображается, к сожалению(

Comment: @Marie Обращайтесь :)